# Prevent javascript component from refreshing my entire page

Tags: xpages, pivottable.js

I am adding pivottable.js (after reading of it here http://www.wissel.net/stw/wisselblog.nsf) into an xPages application. The component loads but I have a problem when the component which allows for filtering of the data, is done on my xPage it refreshes the entire page instead of just the chart.

Here is a demo of the app, You can see that when you hit the drop down on a category you can filter and once that is done it does a partial refresh to filter the data.
http://nicolas.kruchten.com/pivottable/examples/mps.html

On my xPage when I filter the data it refreshes the entire page. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Below is the relevant code. The code not included is just grabbed from the project unmodified but I can include if needed.

I am using using a custom control on the xpage

```
<xc:ccPivot disableTheme="true"></xc:ccPivot></xp:view>
```

Inside the custom control there isn't much. I have tried calling the script at the bottom of the page but that made no change.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="callPivotTable"></script>

 <xp:this.resources>
    <xp:script src="/pivot.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
    <xp:styleSheet href="/pivot.css"></xp:styleSheet>

    <xp:script src="/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"
        clientSide="true">
        </xp:script>
        <xp:script src="/d3_renderers.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
     </xp:this.resources>

 <div id="output" style="margin: 10px;"></div>
```

Here is the callPivotTable script

```
$(function(){
            var derivers = $.pivotUtilities.derivers;

            $.getJSON("./xRest.xsp/restService2", function(mps) {
                $("#output").pivotUI(mps                 

                );
            });
         });
```

You will notice that I am not calling jQuery as a resource here. That is because I am using the bootstrap4xpages extension library which loads jQuery. Not sure if that makes a difference or not.

Here is a link to a working nsf. It is using the bootstrap extension library, and bootstrapv2.3.2 but will load fine in bootstrap3 with the same problems.
[Link to nsf](https://app.box.com/s/0uqfyw4z40nunhp84qhh)

Comment: Show us your relevant code

Comment: Added the code. Let me know if thats enough or if I need to include anything else. Thanks for looking.

Comment: You might need to wrap the pivot into a iframe

Comment: But wouldn't wrapping the pivot still refresh the iframe? Will try it though. Thanks.

Comment: Putting the pivot in an iframe still sends the command to refresh. Whatever js is triggering the refresh, the xpage must see that and trigger a full page refresh.

Comment: I tried going through the pivot.js code to see what is triggering the refresh and seeing if I could disable that; but was not able to.

Comment: What is "<script type="text/javascript" src="callPivotTable"></script>"? Is 'callPivotTable' a variable that returns a function? Try remove that.

Comment: That is the code that gets the data currently its a json url but I can specify an array. How would you propose I arrange this?

Comment: can you create a minimal working NSF and share it somewhere. Would make is easier to test

Comment: Yes that makes a lot of sense I will create that today.

Comment: Thanks, I added a link to a minimal nsf

Comment: I'm the author of PivotTable.js and I believe this has now been fixed in the library with this commit: https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/commit/1ff839d32c4a7245b5f32de6d235c49aa7a5f94e

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, I will apply this to my app. Appreciate you responding here. PivotTable.js is really amazing.

Comment: Great. If you could let me know if that resolves the issue I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to change the pivot.js code. It simply does not work when pivot table is rendered inside form. Any widget refresh forces post of the entire form. Couldn't make it work by code change, so I have turned off the form generation and now it works as expected.

Go to XPage properties (All properties tab) and set property `createForm` to `false`. Or in source it should like like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
    createForm="false">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:script
            src="/pivot.js"
            clientSide="true">
        </xp:script>
        <xp:styleSheet
            href="/pivot.css"></xp:styleSheet>
        <xp:script
            src="/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"
            clientSide="true">
        </xp:script>
        <xp:script
            src="/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"
            clientSide="true">
        </xp:script>
    </xp:this.resources>
    <xp:scriptBlock>
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[$( function() {
    $("#output").pivotUI( [ {
        color : "blue",
        shape : "circle"
    }, {
        color : "red",
        shape : "triangle"
    } ], {
        rows : [ "color" ],
        cols : [ "shape" ]
    });
});]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>
    <div
        id="output"
        style="margin: 10px;">
    </div>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: I am tuned in... Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Thanks for the help Frantisek! That is perfect. And thank you for the explanation. I truly appreciate the help.

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that is seems to disable partial refreshes for other components. So if I want to refresh the json data source with a search parameter I am unable to do so.

Comment: I believe there is a way. Pivot table can be moved outside the form, for example.

Comment: I think this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857479/xpage-createform-false-disables-ssjs-events-on-links